# Creating a custom JsonConverter to handle System.Text.Encoding objects

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have written a custom JsonConverter which I am hoping will allow me to serialize and deserialize [`Encoding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.Encoding(v=vs.110).aspx) objects within my classes:

```
public class EncodingConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Encoding));
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(((Encoding)value).EncodingName);
    }

    public override bool CanRead { get { return true; } }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var name = reader.ReadAsString();
        return Encoding.GetEncoding(name);
    }
}
```

However, when I run the following test code, I get an exception when calling `DeserializeObject`, and the `ReadJson` method never gets called.

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new TestClass();

        var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Converters = new[] { new EncodingConverter(), }
        };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test, jsonSettings);

        var test2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestClass>(json, jsonSettings);
    }
}

class TestClass
{
    public string Property1;
    public Encoding Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
}
```

The exception message is:

> Target type System.Text.Encoding is not a value type or a non-abstract class.

Am I missing something?

Comment: `objectType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Encoding))` evaluates to false.

Comment: your `TestClass` isn't assignable from `Encoding`.Hence `(Encoding)value` is invalid.

Comment: @Amit Kumar Ghosh, this converter is for Encoding objects **only**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three problems with your converter that I see.

1. You are using the wrong check in `CanConvert()`.
2. You are using the wrong name for the `Encoding` when serializing.
3. You are using the wrong method to get the value from the reader when deserializing.

Let's take these one at a time.

First, in your `CanConvert` method you are using `objectType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Encoding))` to determine whether the converter should handle the `Encoding`.  This works fine on serialization because you have a concrete instance of the encoding (e.g. `UTF8Encoding`), which is indeed a subclass of `Encoding`.  However, on deserialization, the deserializer doesn't know what concrete type of encoding you are going to make, so the type that is passed to the converter is just `Encoding`.  Since `Encoding` is not a subclass of itself, `CanConvert` returns false, and your `ReadJson` method never gets called.  That leaves Json.Net to try to instantiate the `Encoding` itself, which it can't do (because `Encoding` is abstract), so it throws the error you mentioned in your question.  You should instead use `typeof(Encoding).IsAssignableFrom(objectType)` inside your `CanConvert` method.

Second, when serializing the `Encoding` inside `WriteJson`, you are outputting the `EncodingName` property, which is the human-readable display name of the encoding, not the code page name.  If you look at the documentation for the [`Encoding.GetEncoding(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a3kf7c(v=vs.110).aspx) method, it says:

> **Parameters**
>
> *name*
>
> Type: System.String
>
> The code page name of the preferred encoding. Any value returned by the WebName property is valid. Possible values are listed in the Name column of the table that appears in the Encoding class topic.

So, you should be outputting the value of the `WebName` property in your `WriteJson` method if you want to be able to use this value to later reconstruct the `Encoding` in `ReadJson`.

Third, in your `ReadJson` method you are using `reader.ReadAsString()` to attempt to get the encoding name from the JSON.  This will not work as you expect.  When `ReadJson` is called by Json.Net, the reader is already positioned at the current value.  When you call `ReadAsString()`, that advances the reader to the *next* token and then attempts to interpret that token as a string.  What you really want to do is just get the value of the current token, which you can do using the `Value` property.  Because `Value` is of type `object`, you will need to cast it to a string.

Here is the corrected code for the converter:

```
public class EncodingConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(Encoding).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(((Encoding)value).WebName);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return Encoding.GetEncoding((string)reader.Value);
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UmLynX

Comment: #1 is what I needed... other 2 are minor problems.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
    public class CustomConverter : JsonConverter
    {

        public override bool CanConvert(System.Type objectType)
        {
            return true;// objectType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Encoding));
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            return Encoding.GetEncoding(Convert.ToString(reader.Value));
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var t = (Test)value;
            var e = (Encoding)t.MyProperty;
            writer.WriteValue(e.BodyName);
            //serializer.Serialize(writer, e.BodyName);
        }
    }
```

And in `Main`:

```
            var o = new Test { MyProperty = Encoding.UTF8 };
            var s = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                Converters = new[] { new CustomConverter() }
            };
            var v = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o, s);
            var o2 = new Test();
            o2.MyProperty = Encoding.GetEncoding(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(v, s).ToString());
```

Comment: My goal is to write a custom converter for a certain type (Encoding), not to write a fully manual all-object serializer. The real type I'm working with is much more complicated, than the sample TestClass.